# Cast datetime not working on select raw query builder but eloquent is ok

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I'm using laravel 5.7 and have a model like this:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'com_tasks';
    ///...
    //protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $casts = [
         'start_date'  => 'datetime:Y/m/d H:i:s',
         'due_date' => 'datetime:Y/m/d H:i:s',
    ];

    /**
     * get list data
     *
     * @param  $params
     * @return array list com_tasks
     */
    public function list($params=[])
    {
        $result = $this->select(
            'com_tasks.id',
            'com_tasks.name',
            'com_tasks.done',
            'com_task_status.id AS status_id',
            'com_task_status.name AS status_name',
            'com_task_status.color AS status_color',
            'com_projects.name AS project_name',
            'com_projects.name AS assignee_name'
        )
        ->selectRaw(DB::raw('
            DATE_FORMAT(com_tasks.start_date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s") as start_date,
            DATE_FORMAT(com_tasks.due_date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s") as due_date
        '))
        ->leftJoin('com_task_status', 'com_tasks.status_id', 'com_task_status.id')
        ->leftJoin('com_projects', 'com_tasks.project_id', 'com_projects.id');

        $per_page = $params['per_page'] ?? config('pagination.per_page');
        return $result->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate($per_page);
    }

///...
}
```

When I bind this model to router, it works fine but when I call: (new Task)->list($conditions); I get an error:

```
{"status":false,"message":"Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.","class":"InvalidArgumentException","file":"D:\\Projects\\backend\\vendor\
esbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Carbon.php","line":909,"code":0}
```

But when I comment $casts variable, it works. Why this happend?

P/S: when I try put 'start_date' to $dates I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all the `list()` method should be part of your controller, as well as you should use Laravel native relationship handlers... Have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

Anyway the problem is that the `$cast` variable is trying to transform your query result into a [`Carbon` object](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation) and after that, format the result as `Y/m/d H:i:s` format. But the input is not a timestamp, it's simply a string (because you're running `DATE_FORMAT(com_tasks.start_date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s") as start_date` in your query). That's why the exception is thrown.

You should simply recover the `start_date` and `due_date` column if you want to use `$cast` or `$dates` attributes. Your code will become:

```php
$result = $this->select(
    'com_tasks.id',
    'com_tasks.name',
    'com_tasks.done',
    'com_task_status.id AS status_id',
    'com_task_status.name AS status_name',
    'com_task_status.color AS status_color',
    'com_projects.name AS project_name',
    'com_projects.name AS assignee_name',
    'com_tasks.start_date AS start_date',
    'com_tasks.due_date AS due_date',
            )
->leftJoin('com_task_status', 'com_tasks.status_id', 'com_task_status.id')
->leftJoin('com_projects', 'com_tasks.project_id', 'com_projects.id');

$per_page = $params['per_page'] ?? config('pagination.per_page');
return $result->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate($per_page);
```

As I was writing at the beginning, the best solution, anyway, should be:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'com_tasks';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'start_date', 'due_date'];

    /**
     * get list data
     *
     * @param  $params
     * @return array list com_tasks
     */
    public function list($params=[])
    {
        $per_page = $params['per_page'] ?? config('pagination.per_page');

        return $this->with(['taskStatus', 'project'])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate($per_page);
    }

    public function taskStatus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TaskStatus::class);
    }

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

and in your controller / blade view / whatever call the format method since the `deleted_at`, `start_date` and `due_date` attributes are instantiated as `Carbon` objects.

```
// ... your code
$model->start_date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');

// ... your blade view

{{ $model->start_date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'); }}
```

Comment: thanks so much, I knew what reason is. I'll try eloquent relation ship.

Comment: your code works fine with select statement but when I try to update or save, I get the same error. I comment $dates and then it works. In migration, start_date and due_date is timestamp.

Comment: In the store / update it's the same story. You have to set the `start_date` / `due_date` as Carbon objects